# AUC values from ROC curves show discrepancies (spss)

Tags: spss, roc

I got two different values for AUC when calculating ROC curves in SPSS (version 24). I have a dataset of 75 samples and 10 variables (ΔCt) for each sample.

First I did ROC analysis for **6 variables**.

Code:

```
ROC ΔCt_1 ΔCt_2 ΔCt_3 ΔCt_4 
    ΔCt_5 ΔCt_6 BY Label (1) 
  /PLOT=CURVE(REFERENCE) 
  /PRINT=SE COORDINATES 
  /CRITERIA=CUTOFF(INCLUDE) TESTPOS(SMALL) DISTRIBUTION(FREE) CI(95) 
  /MISSING=EXCLUDE
```

Results:

[image: Results_6variables]

Then I repeated the analysis for all **10 variables**.

Code:

```
ROC ΔCt_1 ΔCt_2 ΔCt_3 ΔCt_4 
    ΔCt_5 ΔCt_6 ΔCt_7 ΔCt_8 
    ΔCt_9 ΔCt_10 BY Label (1) 
  /PLOT=CURVE(REFERENCE) 
  /PRINT=SE COORDINATES 
  /CRITERIA=CUTOFF(INCLUDE) TESTPOS(SMALL) DISTRIBUTION(FREE) CI(95) 
  /MISSING=EXCLUDE
```

Results:

[image: Results_10variables]

Visually, the curves are the same, but there could be minor differences that are not visible to my eyes. I would like to understand why the same data (for the 6 variables analysed in both calculations) provides different results.

Thank you very much for your help.

Best, Ana

Comment: Are there (user- or system-) missing data in these variables?

Comment: Yes. Excluding such variables makes the results repeatable. Do you have any explanation as to why? I thought it does calculations variable by variable and excludes missing data for each variable separately and not in "bulk".
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ana - ROC uses LISTWISE deletion to make sure that each curve is comparable to (i.e., uses the exact same observations as) the others.